# Finding the range of $S$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, solution-verification

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be a function whose derivatives is on $R$ \ $\{b\}$ and $R$, respectively. The graph of $f'(x)$ and g'(x) is shown below (on the image below). Let: $$h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$$
> and $$S = -[h(b+x^2)]^2 + h(b+x^2) \cdot (1+2h(c)) - [h(c)]^2$$ for $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. Which of the following is true for $x \neq 0$?

> $A. S \in [h(c), h(a+c)] \\ B. S \leq h(c) \\ C. S \in S \in [h(c), h(a+b)] \\ D. S \in [h(a), h(c)]$

> The graph:

[image]

**My solution**:

$$\begin{align}
S & = -[h(b+x^2)]^2 + h(b+x^2) \cdot (1+2h(c)) - [h(c)]^2 \\
& \\
& = -[h(b+x^2)]^2 + 2h(b+x^2)h(c) + h(b+x^2) - [h(c)]^2 \\
& \\
& = - ([h(b+x^2)]^2 - 2h(b+x^2)h(c) + [h(c)]^2) + h(b+x^2) \\
& \\
& = - ([h(b+x^2)] - [h(c)])^2 + h(b+x^2) \\
\end{align}$$

We have: $h'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x)$

- When $x \in [b, c)$: $f'(x) > g'(x)$ so $h(x)$ is increasing. As $x \to b^{+}$, $f'(x) \to +\infty$ and $g'(x) \to g'(b)$, therefore $h'(x) \to + \infty$. This implies $h(x)$ start  from $-\infty$ and going up to $h(c)$
- When $x = c$: $h'(c) = f'(c) - g'(c) = 0$. $h(x)$ stop increasing.
- When $x > c$: $f'(x) < g'(x)$ so $h(x)$ is decreasing.

From those indications, we know that $h(x)$ will only have a local maximum at $x = c$ for $x \in [b, +\infty] \,\, (1)$

Now, since $b + x^2 > b$ for $x \neq 0$ and based on $(1)$, we get:

$$h(b + x^2) \leq h(c)$$

Therefore:

$$S \leq 0 + h(c) = h(c)$$

So $S$ has a maximum of $h(c)$

For the minimum, since $h(b + x^2) \leq h(c)$ and $h(b + x^2) \to -\infty$ as $x \to b^{+}$ or $x \to +\infty$, $S$ can approach $-\infty$ and so there is no minimum for $S$

In conclusion, the answer is $\color{red}{B. S \leq h(c)}$

> Is my solution correct? If yes, does that mean $a$ has no use in the process of solving? (This is also why I'm uncertainly about my answer)

> If not, what did I do wrong? If I wrong at the minimum of $S$, then what is $S_{min}$?